# vb pass name of function using intellisense

Tags: vb.net, reflection, hook

I'm tying to implement a novel way of overriding functions based on which DLLs I have loaded. In this model, I have a list of class instances from First = Highest Priority to Last = Lowest priority.

Any of those classes may implement a Hook function or callback. I'm currently at the stage where I can pass a string to a function, and then call it - my library convention looks like this:

```
Dim hookclasses as HooksList
Dim callable as Object

hookclasses.Add(new ClassA)
hookclasses.Add(new ClassB)
'... etc.

if hookclasses.Has("MyHookFunction", callable) then
    callable.MyHookFunction()
end if
```

This all works, but I'd like to reduce typos by leveraging Intellisense. I've already thought of popping the strings into a class containing constant strings, so I'm after something better than that.

Ideally I'd like to have a fallback class that implements all of the hook functions (even if it simply returns), and if the language supported it, I'd like to do the following:

```
if hookclasses.Has(NameOf(FallbackClass.MyHookFunction), callable) then ...
```

Clearly there is no 'NameOf' operator, and I don't know how to write a NameOf function.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure VB 14 (part of VS 2015) *does* have a `NameOf` operator! :-) But I'm not sure that is the best design. I feel like inheritance is a better, more elegant solution here.

Comment: If you want to use IntelliSense then you must stop using `As Object`.  Use interfaces instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article nameOf (C# and Visual Basic reference)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx

It does exactly what you want. And before that String Litterals were almost the only option.

Edit :

Question was : "Clearly there is no 'NameOf' operator, and I don't know how to write a NameOf function."

If I understand your problem right, you have a list of classes that you fetched from dynamically loaded DLL, point is you don't know if a class implements all of the hooks or only a few.

If you use an interface, like IHookable and put all the hook functions in there, it means all the DLL have to implement all the hook functions, which is not what you want.

And (if I understand it properly) if the first class in list does not implement the hook, you check the second one and so on. So with an interface you wouldn't know if the hook is implemented or not.

Comment: Can you please specify what part of it resolves the issue?

Comment: The question was : "Clearly there is no 'NameOf' operator, and I don't know how to write a NameOf function."